# Mutate value of class using a parallel tool?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a function inside a class, which computes some value and appends it to a class field:

```
import multiprocessing
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = [23, 42]

    def bar_parallel(self):
        print("hello")
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
            p.map(self.bla, range(200))

    def bar_serial(self):
        print("hello")
        for i in range(200):
            self.bla(i)

    def bla(self, x):
        self.items.append(x**2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = Foo()

    print(f.items)
    f.bar_parallel()
    print(f.items)
```

multiprocessing does not work here, as it creates new objects in every process, thus the result of the script above is always:

```
[23, 42]
hello
[23, 42]
```

Is it somehow possible to have the same behaviour as `bar_serial` but parallelized?

This approach would work, but is there a way to avoid it, i.e. have `bla` write directly into the member?

```
def bar_parallel_works(self):
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        self.items.extend(p.map(self.bla_fixed, range(200))

def bla_fixed(self, x):
    return x**2
```

Comment: if you use `map(self.bla, range(200))` in `bar_serial`, you get the same result as in `bar_parallel`.

Comment: @TPVasconcelos really? First of all `map` will do nothing until the generator object is read, thus you would need something like `list(map(self.bla, range(200)))`. Also it is not parallelized.

Comment: @TPVasconcelos oh okay, I understand now. No, I think the problem is that multiprocessing will create new copies. Threading should work though, but there is no nice interface AFAIK.